# Android - listview - default listitem (state) background colour

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles

How can I set the default background colour of the listitems when the list is first shown?

Seems easy ... but wait ...

Context: In a anmiated popup window I would like to show a list of items. I would like to have them an initial colour of "soft_red" (as an example).

Preferably I would like to set it via the XML layout file.

Of course, I tried all kinds of selector examples. "Pressed" and "selected" work fine. 
But after popping up ... the background of the listitems is just white, not red_soft.

My code:

```
final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow( myActivity);
popup.setContentView(layout);
... 
ListView m_listview = (ListView) layout.findViewById( R.id.popup_menu_list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( myActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, menuItems);
m_listview.setAdapter( adapter);
```

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popupLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_list"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selected_flat_colour"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The selector code (in list_selected_flat_colour.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Normal state. WHY IS THIS NEVER USED -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/red_soft"
      android:state_pressed="false" 
      android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- pressed state. OK -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink_soft"
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- Selected state. OK-->
    <item android:drawable="@color/green_soft" 
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by pop up window. Is it that after you click on a listitem you show a dialog with the color.

Comment: The popup window is first created with in it the listview. See the code above. So, the popup appears with a list of white list items. I would like to have them (in this example) red_soft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pfff, found it ...

See http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2012/12/android-set-selection-color-in-listview.html. This is a great tutorial.

Setting the selector via the listview does not work. Setting the selector via the listview **item** works!

Summarized ... the listitem entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:minHeight="15dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

The selector ... that shows red_soft menu items on first sight:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orange_color"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/white_color"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_soft2"/>   
</selector>
```

The color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <drawable name="red_color">#ff0000</drawable>
   <drawable name="white_color">#ffffff</drawable>
   <drawable name="orange_color">#ffffbb33</drawable>
   <drawable name="red_soft2">#f7a1c3</drawable>
</resources>
```

The listview:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/possibleLocationView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

The Adapter:

```
String[] myAddresses = { "Netherlands", "Spain", "US" };
ArrayAdapter<MyAddress> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyAddress>(mContext, R.layout.possible_location_list_layout, myAddresses);
mPossibleLocationListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps you.